# Spring Boot - Unable to resolve Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple Spring boot application from 2 days but still unable to make it work. I checked all the related questions and blogs but still issue persist.

My project structure appears as below.

[image: Project Structure]

POM.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

WebApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/EBS-web
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

LoginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(path="/")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("******************logging************************");
        return "login";
    }

}
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hi Login
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I try to run the application as Spring Boot App (STS plugin for Eclipse) and access the http://localhost:8080/EBS-web/
It gives below error message on UI

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Sep 23 17:34:52 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

From the below stack trace, I can see spring is able to fetch the handler method but not able to find the associated view.

> 2018-09-23 17:44:12.248 DEBUG 14728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for
>   [/EBS-web/] is: -1
>
> ******************logging************************
>
> 2018-09-23 17:44:12.258 DEBUG 14728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are
>   [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng,
>   application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and
>   producible media types [*/*]) 2018-09-23 17:44:12.258 DEBUG 14728 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No
>   matching bean found for view name 'login' 2018-09-23 17:44:12.260
>   DEBUG 14728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL
>   [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
>   2018-09-23 17:44:12.260 DEBUG 14728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL
>   [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcherServlet' 2018-09-23 17:44:12.264 DEBUG 14728 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            :
>   Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] in
>   InternalResourceView 'login' 2018-09-23 17:44:12.266 DEBUG 14728 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request
>   for [/EBS-web/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] 2018-09-23 17:44:12.267 DEBUG
>   14728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping :
>   Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp 2018-09-23
>   17:44:12.268 DEBUG 14728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method
>   for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] 2018-09-23 17:44:12.268 DEBUG 14728 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching
>   patterns for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] are [/**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please define method in your controller: You may define `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` or you may directly use @GetMapping

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping(path="/")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("******************logging************************");
        return "login";
    }

}
```

there might be some more conflicts in your pom, like no need add tomcat dependency as its already embedded so below can be removed.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**To enable support for JSP’s, add a dependency on tomcat-embed-jasper.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and after 2.x release no need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` so below should be sufficient to start.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried updating the code as suggested but still issue is same. :(

Comment: Can you post your code to github and share url, let me see

Comment: There is some problem in configuration. As it says no match bean found or there is a issue of view resolver. Please put you config info so that it will help you to get the solution

Comment: @MayankVaid check my updated answer to add "enable support for JSP’s, add a dependency on tomcat-embed-jasper."

Answer (score 3):

Add `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`. Then run your Java application. this should solve the `WhiteLabel` error

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Can you tell me why did @RestController work instead of @Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure all the classess are under the root package. I spent hours in this error.
My application was running on self defined port 8085,but while hitting that port there was no response. i was not getting error in the console. after restructuring the package under root package. Error is Resolved!!!!!!!!!!

Happy Learning :)

Regards,
Vicky Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Just add your class file inside main generated package then error would get resolved.